# Policy on deletion of factually incorrect answers

Tags: discussion

[This answer](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/6028/99) (quoted below) was confirmed to be factually incorrect when Naruto Chapter 656 was released.

> Actually, issue #1 means first manga release of beginning of the year.
> So it means there's no Naruto manga until the first week of January.

I seek clarification on what is our policy on deletion of this answer, because site policy/guidelines on two different pages seem to be mutually conflicting.

The [Why and how are some answers deleted?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers) page states:

> Answers that do not fundamentally answer the question may be removed.
> This includes answers that are:
>
> - commentary on the question or other answers
> - asking another, different question
> - “thanks!” or “me too!” responses
> - exact duplicates of other answers
> - barely more than a link to an external site
> - not even a partial answer to the actual question

Although the above answer is incorrect, it doesn't seem to violate any of the bullets. However, the [Trusted User Privileges](https://anime.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) states:

> When should I vote to delete an answer?
>
> You may vote to delete answers in the following cases:
>
> - The answer is extremely low quality: There is little to no scope for improvement
> - The answer doesn't answer the question; it may be a comment or a separate question altogether.
> - The answer is not much more than a link to another page. Link only answers are not allowed on Stack Exchange.

It could be argued that a factually incorrect answer is "extremely low quality with little scope for improvement".

Which of these versions should a trusted user follow when deciding on whether to cast a delete vote on an answer?

Comment: I won't answer directly from mobile because that sucks. But basically, the owner can choose to delete the answer. The community shouldn't delete, only vote it down.

Comment: http://anime.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-down *Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or **an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect**.* No deletion, only downvotes if it's wrong. (If there's nothing else that justifies deletion)

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Do you have a source for this? I've seen it claimed many times that *moderators* should not delete answers for being factually incorrect, but I can find no information suggesting that the community is supposed to follow the same rule. Frankly, if a post that is blatantly and totally factually incorrect doesn't qualify as "extremely low quality: There is little to no scope for improvement", then I'm not sure what that point is supposed to mean at all.

Comment: @LoganM There were many discussions about that over at meta SO: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/141857/201616 Many other good questions about that can be found searching for the tag `low quality posts`

Comment: @LoganM: "[ANS] Note that wrong answers should not be deleted: deletion is for answers that “aren't even wrong”." from the link looper posted. Factually wrong answers (but that **are** answers) should not be deleted.

Comment: Okay thanks, that seems to clear that up.

Comment: One way I could logically agree with not deleting wrong answers is this.  If I see an answer with -10 and a comment that says "This is wrong" then I know not to bother with it.  Alternative is I saw the suggestion elsewhere and try it, only to make things worse.  On Arqade, you can also add in what version of the game it used to work on, but not so relevant here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the text from the link looper posted above related to deleting answers:

> You should **Delete** a post
>
> - If the post is rude or offensive [possibly flag]
> - [QUES] If the question has been [closed for a while](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138686/how-long-should-i-wait-before-deleting-a-closed-question)
> - [ANS] If the answer asks another question
> - [ANS] If an answer is actually a comment (such as asking for more info, thanks!, etc.) [possibly flag]
> - [ANS] If the answer is incomprehensible and you are at least a bit familiar with the subject.
> - [ANS] If the answer duplicates another, better answer to the same question (e.g. a link-only answer where another answer provides the same link with an explanation).
> - [ANS] Is obvious spam (tries to sell you cheap sunglasses) [possibly flag].
> - [ANS] **Note that wrong answers should not be deleted:** deletion is for answers that “aren't even wrong”.

So "just" being wrong is not sufficient to be worthy of deletion if it doesn't have any of the above problems. It does not seem that there is any way for me to remove my deletion vote on that answer, so it'll have to stay there unless there's some way I'm not aware of.

Comment: Looks like to remove the delete vote, we need a mod. [How does a trusted user remove their delete vote on an answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/209433/202356) I am assuming that the OP won't be deleting and undeleting the answer any time soon.

Comment: @Happy Yeah that's what I figured. I'm fine with a mod deleting and undeleting the answer if they want to clear the votes, but I have plenty more deletion votes so it's not particularly important. I'll leave it up to them to decide whether to clear the votes in this case, but I don't think we should set a precedent that mods will do this anytime an answer mistakenly gets a deletion vote.

Comment: Yeah, I guess there's no great harm done by a few delete votes. If the OP has an issue with it or it accumulates enough delete votes to actually get deleted, then it is appropriate for the mods to intervene. For now though, I think we are done with this.